# What is the usage of "wore on"?

Tags: grammar

> 22- It was hard work and, as the day ……………, I became more and more tired.
>   a) wore on
>   b) wore out
>   c) wore off
>   d) wore down

The answer is "wore on": what is the meaning of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "wear on" is an expression used about periods of time to express their slow passing:

> **wear** 4 [ *intrans*. ] ( wear on) (of a period of time) pass, esp. slowly or tediously : *as the afternoon wore on, he began to look unhappy*. [NOAD]

Comment: +1. The connotation is that most "wear", damage caused by friction or weathering, happens very slowly. So, to use the term "wore on" implies two feelings; first, that the passage of time seems very slow, and second, that the slow passage is somehow painful or mentally degrading.